# SharePoint as digital documents library and search function

Tags: search, list-view-threshold

I want to use Sharepoint as a digital document library and the listview threshold limit is getting in the way, I want to increase the threshold limit to a very big number... lets say a million (1,000,000) or more ..

May I know is it safe to do so ?

and regarding the Search function above and on the upper right hand corner of each "view", may i know how does it work or what does it search ??

Answer (score 1):

Why is the listview threshold limit getting in the way?
It's not limiting the number of documents you can have in a library, but only how many you can see in a view and showing 1,000,000 documents will take forever.
You probably want to create views which only show part of the content.

The search box goes to the search page of the site, searches the search application assoiciated with the current web application for content in this site.

Comment: hi, for example, i set the limit to 25000, the 25001th file I uploaded will appear, but the 1st file will be gone from the view, and if I want to search from the view, the file seems to be dissappear. I was wondering is there any alternatives to search for the files ?

Comment: Search is a lot better for searching than looking through 1,000,000 items manually